# barplot of different group with conditions

Tags: r

I am working on a data science project at work and my goal is to provide a summary out of the huge dataset.

For instance, I want to know how many customers ordered the House Brand one time, two times, more than two times. 
How many ordered the house brand and the nonHouse Brand? 
How many ordered just the nonHouse Brand?

How can I achieve this?

Sample dataset

```
PRODUCT_SUB_LINE_DESCR    MAJOR_CATEGORY_DESCR       CUST_REGION_DESCR
SUNDRY                         SMALL EQUIP           NORTH EAST REGION
SUNDRY                         SMALL EQUIP           SOUTH EAST REGION
SUNDRY                         SMALL EQUIP           SOUTH EAST REGION
SUNDRY                         SMALL EQUIP           NORTH EAST REGION
SUNDRY                         PREVENTIVE            SOUTH CENTRAL REGION
SUNDRY                         PREVENTIVE            SOUTH EAST REGION
SUNDRY                         PREVENTIVE            SOUTH EAST REGION
SUNDRY                         SMALL EQUIP           NORTH CENTRAL REGION
SUNDRY                         SMALL EQUIP           MOUNTAIN WEST REGION
SUNDRY                         SMALL EQUIP           MOUNTAIN WEST REGION
SUNDRY                         COMPOSITE             NORTH CENTRAL REGION
SUNDRY                         COMPOSITE             NORTH CENTRAL REGION
SUNDRY                         COMPOSITE             OHIO VALLEY REGION
SUNDRY                         COMPOSITE             NORTH EAST REGION

Sales   QtySold      MFGCOST    MarginDollars   new_ProductName
209.97  3             134.55    72.72            no
-76.15  -1            -44.85    -30.4            no
275.6   2             162.5     109.84           no
138.7   1             81.25     55.82            no
226     2             136       87.28            no
115     1             68        45.64            no
210.7   2             136       71.98            no
29      1             18.85     9.77             no
29      1             18.85     9.77             no
46.32   2             37.7      7.86             no
159.86  1             132.4     24.81            no
441.3   2             264.8     171.2            no
209.62  1             132.4     74.57            no
209.62  1             132.4     74.57            no
```

This is not the original dataset. I basically added a new column to my original data set for my Decision Tree Analysis later. But for now, I want to produce some plots here. Private Label is considered to be House Brand.

```
 new_ProductName = ifelse( PRODUCT_SUB_LINE_DESCR == "PRIVATE 
                          LABEL","yes","no")
 data = data.frame(new_Dataset, new_ProductName)
```

Issue:

```
> group_by_region = data %>% group_by(PRODUCT_SUB_LINE_DESCR, 
      CUST_REGION_DESCR) %>% summarise(count=n(), sales=sum(Sales))

> mytable = table(group_by_region)
> barplot(mytable)
Error in barplot.default(mytable) : 'height' must be a vector or a matrix
```

Comment: You can use the function `table` to get counts of your data, and then put them into a `barplot` .  If you encounter an error please edit your question with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Esther I edited one.

Comment: What is `group_by_region` in this case? Is it your whole dataset?

Comment: @Esther Update my post.

Comment: @Esther I really need some help. Please

Comment: In this case since you have used already used `group_by` you don't need to use `table`, but can call a barplot like so `barplot(group_by_region$count, names=group_by_region$CUST_REGION_DESCR)` . Since it seems like you are using `tidyverse` code you can also you the `geom_bar` from `ggplot2` to make barplots.

Comment: @Esther  I will work on that. I just don’t know the exact syntax for ggplot2. Anyway, referring to my original question, what is your suggestion to make a plot of customer purchasing the products based on some criteria such as how many ordered house brand one time? Two times? More than two times?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172553/discussion-between-esther-and-adam-ralphus).